# missing right parenthesis while inserting record in polygon a sdo_geomety data type column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-spatial

I have created a table in oracle 11g

```
  CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."CN_PLOT_OVERLAP" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "UNIT_CODE" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE), 
    "SEASON_CNTRL" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "RYOT_CODEE" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE), 
    "SHARE_OR_PERC_VAL" NUMBER(1,2), 
    "PLOT_NO" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "TOTAL_AREA" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "LAT1" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "LNG1" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "LAT2" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "LNG2" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "LAT3" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "LNG3" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "LAT4" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "LNG4" BINARY_FLOAT, 
    "POLYGON" "SDO_GEOMETRY", 
     CONSTRAINT "ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
```

and already inserted values expecting **polygon**. Now when I am inserting values for **Polygon** it shows an error

```
**SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
1. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"**
```

Basically I have four coordinates of a farm and inserting it in this column using following sql

```
update cn_plot_overlap set polygon = (1,
  MDSYS.sdo_geometry(
  2003,
  4326,
  NULL,
  sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,1),
  sdo_ordinate_array(27.79094,80.5275449,   
                      27.7912333,80.527696, 
                      27.79085,80.5285083,
                      27.790571,80.5283216,
                      27.79094,80.5275449
                      )
                    )
                    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `1` in the first line of your `UPDATE`? It shouldn't be there. This is how you should create `SDO_GEOMETRY` object:

```
update cn_plot_overlap set polygon = 
  MDSYS.sdo_geometry(
  2003,
  4326,
  NULL,
  sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,1),
  sdo_ordinate_array(27.79094,80.5275449,   
                      27.7912333,80.527696, 
                      27.79085,80.5285083,
                      27.790571,80.5283216,
                      27.79094,80.5275449
                      )
                    );
```

I also do not recommend creating any objects in `SYS` user's schema.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer, I also don't understand the meaning of the "1" in your update. Unless you somehow expect it to be the identifier of the object for which you want to fill the POLYGON column. If so, then you need to write the update like shown below.

Note that you also have a problem with the ordinates: Oracle (like pretty much everyone else) expects the coordinates to be provided in (X,Y) order, i.e. in (longitude,latitude). As written, your farm is located somewhere in the Arctic ocean! If you write the coordinates correctly, it will be correctly located in India:

```
update cn_plot_overlap set polygon = 
  sdo_geometry(
    2003,
    4326,
    NULL,
    sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,1),
    sdo_ordinate_array(
      80.5275449,27.79094,   
      80.527696,27.7912333, 
      80.5285083,27.79085,
      80.5283216,27.790571,
      80.5275449,27.79094
    )
  )
where id = 1;
```

If you want to update the polygon column using the values available in columns LATn,LNGn for all rows in your table, then use the following syntax:

```
update cn_plot_overlap set polygon = 
  sdo_geometry(
    2003,
    4326,
    NULL,
    sdo_elem_info_array(1,1003,1),
    sdo_ordinate_array(
      lng1,lat1,
      lng2,lat2,
      lng3,lat3,
      lng4,lat4,
      lng1,lat1
    )
  );
```

This assuming that the LATn,LNGn columns represent the corner in the expected sequence (i.e. counter-clockwise). If this is not the case, just reverse the order of coordinates.

And finally, as already mentioned: NEVER, NEVER, NEVER create objects (tables) in any system schema!!! This is a sure guarantee of future trouble. Create your tables in your own schemas.